# How can I display of 2 different QTextEdit values into a QLabel

Tags: c++, qt

Im trying to simply display of 2 different `QTextEdit` value into a `QLabel`. I have tried for a single `QTextEdit` but couldn't display the value of both `QTextEdit`.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{    
  ui->label_az->setText(ui->textEdit_ra1->toPlainText());
  ui->label_az->setText(ui->textEdit_ra2->toPlainText());
}
```

It doesn't display the `QTextEdit` values when I click on `pushbutton`. Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you looking for `ui->label_az->setText(ui->textEdit_ra1->toPlainText()+ui->textEdit_ra2->toPlainText());`?

Comment: @Mike i want to display the both in label_az. tell me how can i do that. thank you

Comment: What is wrong with @Mike solution? At the most you'd want to add some separator...

Comment: @cbuchart .. its not working

Comment: Something else missing? button correctly connected, maximum width of the `QLabel`...?

Comment: BTW, "not working" means: nothing displayed, only the text of one of the `QTextEdit`, truncated text...?

Comment: @cbuchart.  error: stray '\342' in program

Comment: It seems that you have wrong quotation marks... be sure you're using the correct ones (straight quotation marks, not the curly ones). It usually happens when copying text from webpages or documentation that has been formatted not like code but like normal text. It may happen with other UNICODE characters too. Type the code by your self.

Comment: @cbuchart. thank you Sir, its works now

Comment: Thanks @Mike for the initial solution, glad to help with the error! Mike, post your solution as an answer so the question can be closed

Comment: @cbuchart , thanks for your kind help. Feel free to post it, as I am about to go out now :)

Comment: Thanks @Mike, done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to summarize our comments into a single post: [`QLabel::setText`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#text-prop) replaces the content of the label, so you have to create the whole string before and set it once. Code below will do it:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  ui->label_az->setText(
    ui->textEdit_ra1->toPlainText() +
    " " + // use here the separator you find more convenient
    ui->textEdit_ra2->toPlainText());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second `setText()` call *replaces* the label's text.  You want to *combine* both texts into a single label text, like this:

```
label->setText(text_1->toPlainText() + "\n" + text_2->toPlainText());
```

Here's a complete example program, to give context:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QApplication>

#include <memory>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app{argc, argv};

    const auto w = std::make_unique<QWidget>();
    const auto window = w.get();
    const auto layout = new QVBoxLayout(window);
    const auto text_1 = new QTextEdit(window);
    layout->addWidget(text_1);
    const auto text_2 = new QTextEdit(window);
    layout->addWidget(text_2);
    const auto button = new QPushButton("Push Me!", window);
    layout->addWidget(button);
    const auto label = new QLabel(window);
    layout->addWidget(label);

    QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::pressed,
                     label, [=]() { label->setText(text_1->toPlainText() + "\n" + text_2->toPlainText()); });

    window->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be greatly improved if it included an explanation of how it addresses the question. Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @EdM, if you look carefully, you might notice that the first line of the answer explains that the second call is replacing the text set in the first call, rather than appending to it.  This is definitely *not* a low-quality code-only answer.